# Need to schedule R script that can run in 2 hours interval

Tags: r, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule R script or batch file that can run each 2 hours irrespective of user logged in or not/ System is in sleep or lock.

I have tried all the methods mentioned [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d47d116e-10b9-44f0-9a30-7406c86c2fbe/scheduled-task-wont-run-bat-file?forum=winservermanager). Whenever the system locks it stops running.

I am able to schedule it when System is on but fail to do when it is in sleep mode or lock. I have already put option sleep to "Never" . My system does't have admin right so will not able to access "Local Security Policy". Suggest any solution for this where I can schedule it.

Comment: It seems like you have no problem with the *programming* side of things, just the *OS* side of things. Is that what you believe to be the source of the problem? How are you submitting the job to be run, via the Windows interface or via an R package?

Comment: via Windows interface

Comment: Then I suggest two things: (1) this has nothing to do with the [tag:r] tag; and (2) this question is likely better suited for superuser.com, as it is about system administration and not about programming.